# Shouldn't `display:none` completely hide an element

Tags: css

In the following example from https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/b/blank/, why is the paragraph box still visible even though its `display` is set to `none` using `::blank`?

```css
p {
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
p:blank {
  display: none;
}
p:-moz-only-whitespace {
  display: none;
}
/* Mozilla-only pseudo-class that works like :blank will */
```

```html
<div class="blanks">
  <p>This paragraph is not empty or blank.</p>
  <p>
    <!--this is empty and blank -->
  </p>
  <p>

    <!-- this is not empty, because it has whitespace. But it is blank.-->

  </p>
  <p>This paragraph is not empty or blank.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Only Firefox currently supports it

Answer (score 1):

From your reference [css-tricks `::blank`demo](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/b/blank/):

*"At the time of this writing, :blank is part of the CSS Selectors Level 4 draft, and is not supported by any browser."*

The codepen **does** work in Firefox 57.0 though, because of Mozilla's prefix `p:-moz-only-whitespace {display: none;}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `:blank`, maybe try `:empty` instead? I've heard that works in all major browsers. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you have not tried this, why are you recommending it?